# How does the Google Maps app let you drag the BottomSheet when it's behind the BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, android-touch-event

See this video so you know what I'm talking about. Notice how the `BottomSheet` can be dragged even when it's behind the `BottomNavigationView`:

https://streamable.com/balbx

I want to do the same thing but with a `LinearLayout` containing `Button`s instead. I've tried numerous things and none work. I've subclassed `LinearLayout`so that I can override `onInterceptTouchEvent`, and I'm using a `GestureListener` to detect a scroll.

I've posted a barebones test project on Github:

https://github.com/gavingt/BottomSheetTest

Or you can check out the relevant code below:

Here's `MyLinearLayout`:

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

GestureDetector gestureDetector;
boolean isScrolling = false;

public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureListener());
}

public MyLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureListener());
}

public MyLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureListener());
}


@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return isScrolling;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    isScrolling = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return isScrolling;
}




class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                            float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Log.i("TAG", "onScroll: ");

        return true;
    }

}

}
```

And here's `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="262dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"/>

    <com.gavinsappcreations.bottomsheettest.MyLinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/first_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#00F"
            android:paddingLeft="9dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="first button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="17dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/second_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#00F"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="second button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>

    </com.gavinsappcreations.bottomsheettest.MyLinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem thanks to [a Reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/b7mucl/how_does_the_google_maps_app_let_you_drag_the/?st=ju0fc884&sh=8300cb41).

The solution was to use his DelegatingLayout:

https://gist.github.com/davidliu/c246a717f00494a6ad237a592a3cea4f

See the Github project for the full implementation:

https://github.com/gavingt/BottomSheetTest

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try this out:

1. Set up a `transparent RelativeLayout` beneath your `LinearLayout` and above the `google maps fragment`.
2. When this `transparent RelativeLayout` is `touched` then set the focus to the `google maps fragment`
3. If the `LinearLayout` is touched then change the `focus` back to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not an answer either this should be a comment or post code to explain your above statements.